# AspectJ with Spring IOException in certain situtations

Tags: spring, aspectj, ioexception

with my AspectJ Spring application when ever I use ProceedingJoinPoint as an argument or when ever I attempt to capture from all controllers e.g hello.controllers.*
I get an I/O Exception. This however does not occur when I reference the class directly and use only JointPoint not ProceedingJointPoint.

> [2017-09-06 10:01:17,311] Artifact daniel2:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ProceedingJoinPoint is only supported for around advice. Please see server.log for more details.

My AspectJ file

```
@Aspect
public class XSSAspect {
    @Around(value = "execution(* hello.controllers.*(..))")
    public void before(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i] instanceof String) {
                String s = (String) arguments[i];
                s = "testing";
                arguments[i] = s;
            }
        }

        joinPoint.proceed(arguments);
    }
}
```

Dispatcher servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="xssAspect" class="hello.aspect.XSSAspect" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="hello" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="268435456"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory"  init-method="createConfiguration"
          class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/freemarker"/>
        <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*******" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="*********" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
        <property name="username" value="**********"/>
        <property name="password" value="********"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="TaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
        <property name="daemon" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>


    <bean name="VehicleDao" class="hello.dao.VehicleDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="ModelDao" class="hello.dao.ModelDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="ManufactureDao" class="hello.dao.ManufactureDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="UserDao" class="hello.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="CurrencyDao" class="hello.dao.CurrencyDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="ProposalDao" class="hello.dao.ProposalDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="AcceptedProposalDao" class="hello.dao.AcceptedProposalDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="ManufactureModelDao" class="hello.dao.ManufactureModelDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="UploadDao" class="hello.dao.UploadDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="VehicleService" class="hello.services.VehicleServiceImpl">
        <property name="vehicleDao" ref="VehicleDao" />
        <property name="manufactureModelDao" ref="ManufactureModelDao" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="UserService" class="hello.services.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="UserDao" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="CurrencyService" class="hello.services.CurrencyServiceImpl">
    </bean>
    <bean name="ManufactureService" class="hello.services.ManufactureServiceImpl">
    </bean>
    <bean name="ProposalService" class="hello.services.ProposalServiceImpl">
        <property name="proposalDao" ref="ProposalDao"></property>
        <property name="acceptedProposalDao" ref="AcceptedProposalDao"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="ModelService" class="hello.services.ModelServiceImpl">
    </bean>
    <bean name="EmailService" class="hello.services.EmailServiceImpl">
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="TaskExecutor" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="UploadService" class="hello.services.StandardUploadService">
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>


    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <context:component-scan base-package="hello" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven  />
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

MessageAPIController

```
package hello.controllers;

import hello.api.APIResponse;
import hello.api.UploadAPIResponse;
import hello.aspect.AntiJavascript;
import hello.models.Upload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Controller
public class MessageAPIController extends APIController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showMessage(String message, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
         model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return new String("message");
    }
}
```

I have struggled with this issue for hours and would appreciate any insight.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.From the last sentence of your Exception stack ,we can find the reason,"ProceedingJoinPoint is only supported for around advice. Please see server.log for more details."[SEE THE PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bj7P.png)

2."ProceedingJoinPoint" can only be used with "@Around ",but you use it with "@Before".

Comment: Thank you that solved the first issue when referencing the controller directly. the second issue I can not map with:@Around(value = "execution(* hello.controllers.*(..))") Any idea what the issue is thank you.

Comment: you can change like this:@Around("execution(* hello.controllers.MessageAPIController..*.*(..))")

Comment: Thanks for your response. That didn't solve the issue. I also want all controllers to be affected not just the MessageAPIController.

Comment: sorry, i just copy from your question.you can change like this:@Around("execution(* hello.controllers..*.*(..))")

Comment: Thanks cameron I still get an I/O Exception.

java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH